# Does having more threads lead to smaller time slices?

Tags: multithreading, cpu, computer-science, scheduling

I'm trying to understand why having too many threads can reduce CPU usage due to the increased overhead of context switching. An explanation that sounded plausible to me is that increasing # of threads also increases the frequency of context switches, meaning we end up spending more time context switching and less time doing useful work. Is this correct? Do individual time slices get compressed (with more context switches in between) as we have more threads to schedule?

Comment: 'too many threads' -> 'too many ready threads'.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no.  The primary mechanism for lower overhead is that if the scheduler picks the same thread to run on a core for two timeslices in a row, there is no context-switch overhead of stale caches and an FP save/restore.

A "tickless" kernel might set a timer farther in the future if there aren't any other tasks to schedule, instead of the traditional design of having a timer interrupt every 1 or 10 milliseconds where it always calls a scheduler function.  (And if there aren't any waiting tasks, it can trivially decide to keep running this one.)